# Indication on the page, when website not loading

Tags: javascript, html, timeout, runtime-error, loading

How to make a visible indication on the page when service foursquare API not loading (failed to load) ? For below code;

```
 const fourSquare = PlacesAPI.getFoursquareData();

 PlacesAPI.getPlaces().then(places => {

 for (let i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {

    let apiUrl = fourSquare.baseUrl + places[i].foursquareID + fourSquare.picSuffix;

    PlacesAPI.getFoursquarePicture(apiUrl).then(pictureUrl => {

      places[i].picture = pictureUrl;
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Tag the programming language / framework. You will have more possibilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could include a "spinner" on the page, and then hide it once the loading is finished.
*(The included spinner came from [spinkit](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/))*

```js
const spinner = document.getElementById('spinner');
new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('Started loading...');
    
    // Simulate work...
    setTimeout(resolve, 3000);
  }
).then(() => {
  console.log('Finished loading!');

  // Hide the spinner
  spinner.style.display = 'none'; 
})
```

```css
.spinner {
  margin: 100px auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.spinner > div {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100%;
  width: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  
  -webkit-animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-stretchdelay 1.2s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.spinner .rect2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.1s;
  animation-delay: -1.1s;
}

.spinner .rect3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

.spinner .rect4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.9s;
  animation-delay: -0.9s;
}

.spinner .rect5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.8s;
  animation-delay: -0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%, 40%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4) }  
  20% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-stretchdelay {
  0%, 40%, 100% { 
    transform: scaleY(0.4);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.4);
  }  20% { 
    transform: scaleY(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner" id="spinner">
  <div class="rect1"></div>
  <div class="rect2"></div>
  <div class="rect3"></div>
  <div class="rect4"></div>
  <div class="rect5"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think about some easy solution in the case when for example the service is not responding and then the user sees on the screen only sentence " The service is not available at the moment, please try again later " or sth like this and nothing more...

Comment: @Rainbowski erm... then just reverse the logic and use a text field instead of a spinner... the same theory applies.